# Assigning typescript types using interfaces in parenthesis, what's the meaning of the parenthesis?

Tags: typescript, interface, declaration

I have these 2 interfaces

```
export interface Contact {
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
  emails?: (EmailsEntity)[] | null;
  company: string;
  job_title: string;
}
export interface EmailsEntity {
  email: string;
  label: string;
}
```

what's the meaning of assigning `emails?: (EmailsEntity)[] | null;` with `EmailsEntity` in parenthesis?

What the difference with this notation: `emails?: EmailsEntity[] | null;`?

Comment: It's interesting that when I formatted the above code with prettifier the formatter itself removed the parenthesis. So it looks like they are redundant. Go figure.

Answer (score 1):

It actually means nothing. Syntax-wise, it is similar to this:

```
emails?: EmailsEntity[] | null;
```

The usage of parentheses is unnecessary in this case. It is only necessary when it comes to changing the priority of the operators. Read more about [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), and you may understand the full picture.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between `(EmailsEntity)[]` and `EmailsEntity[]`. Typescript allows `()` because when using some type operators, it is necessary to modify the default priority of the operators. Unless the `()` are part of a function signature, they do not have any other meaning in types.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgUQFtMEAbAZ3xQRgE84BvAKDlbmGLIC45yYpkAcwDcLNqUwAjYKR58BSEUwC+TJnTB4AsrQCqSBBCQBGOAF5GcTHP5C4yuAB8CnClRg16AMkvYekiAhSYEwkeyYAegjGa15bRWF7J0sOElk4hRE4CWl0+SFEvzgAoJCkRNV1Wk04HX1DJAAmczgACgYrG0yk5yI0ymo6AEo4Hw6ikuDQ8Ki2OfnWAD0FldWV5cjojtj8hLgJwKnynpTXLoLsqRlzvYPS0IqgA), where parentheses do matter:

```
type MyUnion1 = { a: string } | EmailsEntity & { c: boolean }
// {a: string; } | { email: string; label: string; c: boolean; }

type MyUnion2 = ({ a: string } | EmailsEntity) & { c: boolean }
//              ^                            ^ 
// { a: string; c: boolean; } | { email: string; label: string; c: boolean; }
```

The `&` (intersection) operator has higher precedence than `|` (union). Parentheses will change the priority.

Answer (score 0):

In the given example, there is no difference. However, consider the example below:

```
const b: (string | number)[] = [1, 1];
const a: (string | number)[] = ['Hello!', 'Hello!'];
const c: (string | number)[] = [1, 'Hello!'];
```

In the above, the type annotation of the three arrays includes parantheses. An array with this type annotation can have **all numbers**, **all strings**, or a **mix of both**!

Now look at this example:

```
const d: string[] | number[] = [1, 1];
const e: string[] | number[] = ['Hello!', 'Hello!'];
// const f: string[] | number[] = [1, 'Hello!']; // ERROR
```

In this example, the type annotation of the three arrays does not include parentheses. An array with this type annotation can have **all numbers** or **all strings**, but **NOT** a **mix of both**.